Onscreen touch keyboard pops up but doesn't type with touch(does with mouse) ubuntu 24.04
I have a Yoga i9 with touch display running the latest ubuntu 24.04.01 that mostly works in ubuntu scrolling and clicking browser stuff although not fully as it can open the side menu but not click on it with the touch not I'm also trying to make the onscreen keyboard work and it does pop up when clicking text boxes but work enter input pressed  by the touch screen although it light's the screen key up when pressed but does work when pressing on it with the mouse pointer.
Any idea how to fix this?
